# two possible filters for entry of filter_input_array (php)

Tags: php, arrays, validation, input, filter

I would like to check if a value of an array for example is either an email adress or fits in a Regex.

If there are two filters that would together do exactly what I want:

- is it possible to use these two existing filters and if the first one doesn't fit, check if the second one does?
- or do I have to create a [filter callbac](https://www.php.net/manual/de/filter.filters.misc.php) anyways?

For creating a usecase:
A Login situation, where you either can use an emailadress or a username, but the input field for both is the same.

Pseudocode:

```
    $options = [
        'username' =>
        [
            'options' => [
                
                'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL | FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
                'regexp' => '/([A-Za-z0-9_-]{1,25})/'],
        ],
    ];


    $filteredPost = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $options);
```

If something like this is possible, how?

Comment: I think it shoold be `'options' => ['regexp' => '/.../']`

Comment: Thank you I updated the pseudocode.
At the moment the result to this is that it accept everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can combine multiple filters like this -- you can only use `|` to combine a filter with flags.

In addition, you haven't formed the options array correctly. The regexp needs to be nested further.

```
$options = [
    'username' => [
        'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL | FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
        'options' => [
            'regexp' => '/([A-Za-z0-9_-]{1,25})/'],
    ],
];
```

Each element of `$options` is an array containing `filter` and `options` keys.

Comment: true. my mistake. Sadly this doesn't slove the problem. In this way it is just accepting the email.

I start to think that my question it is not sloveable / i need to create a callback function for it.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you can combine different filters with `|`. You can only use `|` to combine filters with flags.